# Передача массива в функцию

Tags: c, c++

Осваиваю с/с++ для работы с CUDA, застрял в массивах.
Собственно как передать массив в функцию? 
есть код

```
 void print(int ** m);

int main()
{
    int b[5][5] ={{ 1,2,3, 4,5},{ 1,2,3, 4,5},{ 1,2,3, 4,5},{ 1,2,3, 4,5},{ 1,2,3, 4,5}};

    print((int **)b);
    return 0;
}
void print(int **m){

    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        for(int j =0; j<SIZE; j++){
            printf(" %d", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Компилируется но вылетает постоянно при прпытке доступа к m[i][j]. В чем проблема?

Comment: а чему у вас равен SIZE?

Comment: #define SIZE 4

это не выход за пределы массива, на сколько я понял, но что-то рядом...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос о передаче многомерных массивов в функцию уже много раз здесь обсуждался.

Передавать можно двумя способами: передавая либо переменную типа многомерного массива, либо простой указатель.

**Способ 1.**

```
void print  (int m[][5]) {    
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        for(int j =0; j<SIZE; j++){
            printf(" %d", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }     
}
.....
print (b);
```

**Способ 2**

```
const int SIZE = 5; //Именно 5 !!!
void print (int* m) {
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        for(int j =0; j<SIZE; j++){
            printf(" %d", m + SIZE*i + j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
}

.....
print ((int*) b);
```

И указатель на указатель тут не при чем.

Если будет что непонятно, спрашивайте.

И еще: для работы в CUDA очень хорошо проработайте темы указателей и адресации членов многомерных массивов.

Comment: Вы уверены, что в первом способе именно `void print (int m[5][])`? Мне казалось, надо `void print  (int m[][5])`.

Comment: @VladD, Вы абсолютно правы. 

Надо 

    f(int m[][SIZE]) { ...

Comment: Спасибо, вы все правы. Поправил.

Answer (score 5):

Во-первых, прекрасный ответ [[[[@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg).

Во-вторых, вот вам концептуально чистое решение: если вы уж пишете на C++, пользуйтесь идиомами C++, они покажутся вам более интуитивными. В частности, вместо нативных массивов используйте std::vector. Ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void print(const vector< vector<int> >& v)
{
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        for (auto it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); ++it2)
            cout << *it2;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector< vector<int> > b(5);
    for (auto it = b.begin(); it != b.end(); ++it)
        *it = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    print(b);
    return 0;
}
```

В-третьих, проведём разбор ошибок. Давайте я объясню, что пошло не так. `int**` -- это указатель на *массив указателей*, верно? А вот `int[5][5]` -- это вовсе не массив указателей! Это непрерывный кусок памяти, к которому компилятор знает, как доступаться по индексу, потому что он знает размер каждой *строки* вашей таблицы. Поэтому-то `print(b);` у вас не откомпилировалось, типы ведь разные, расположение элементов в памяти не совместимо! Когда вы жёстким кастом преобразуете его в `int**`, у вас указатель на первый элемент таблицы интерпретируется как указатель на список указателей, разумеется, это не сработает. Запомните: если вам нужен cast, возможно, что-то идёт не так.

В-четвёртых, если вы всё же остаётесь с нативными массивами, вот вам вариация ответа [[[[@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg) ближе к стилю C++ (идея с темплейтом позаимствована на SO):

```
template <int LINESIZE>
void print (int m[][LINESIZE]) {    
    for(int i=0; i<LINESIZE; i++){
        for(int j =0; j<LINESIZE; j++){
            printf(" %d", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }     
}
```

В-пятых, вот вам ещё один вариант, который, возможно, лучше. Чтобы расположение элементов в памяти было совместимо с двойным указателем, вы могли бы строки таблицы вручную:

```
const int SIZE = 5;

void print(int** m)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            printf(" %d", m[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

// ...
int** b = new int*[SIZE];
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    b[i] = new int[SIZE];
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        b[i][j] = j;
}
print(b);
```

Comment: @VladD, поскольку человек стремиться к CUDA, ему надо поработать с чистыми массивами. А до boost::multi_array ему еще далеко (кстати, прекрасная библиотека для работы с многомерными массивами).

Comment: @mikillskegg: пожалуй, вы правы. Добавил ещё один вариант.